# Easiest way to read a null terminate string with istream?

Tags: c++, istream

I have an istream and i need to read exactly a specific amount of bytes BUT i dont know the length of it. It is null terminated. I was thinking i could either 1) Write a loop and read one byte at a time 2) Tell it to return me a buffer or string which starts now until a certain byte (0 in this case). or 3) Read into a buf exactly one byte at a time and check it for 0 and append it to string if it isnt.

The 3rd i know i can do but the other 2 sounds like it may be possible with istream (its a filestream in this case). I am still reading documentation for istream. Theres a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you don't know the length of it the simplest would be:

```
std::string strBuf;
std::getline( istream, strBuf, '\0' );
```

Comment: You actually need to use '\0' instead of 0. Otherwise your code doesnt work as expected. It too me a bit to figure that out

Comment: @acidzombie24: There should be no difference (the ASCII value of `\0` is 0) unless in your library there is an overload for `getline()` that accepts an `int` as a third parameter. What error were you getting?

Comment: I'm sure it has to do with a int VS char overload. Here is an example http://codepad.org/YRDKVmNs vs your int example http://codepad.org/KwIjtaof

Comment: @acidzombie: Huh, it seems like it can't auto-convert `int` to `char`, which I guess makes sense in the general case since they're of different sizes. Good to know! My theory about the overload is totally wrong.

Comment: @acidzombie, @cameron: from the "doesn't work as expected" I thought that it had problems at runtime. Tnx for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Number 2) is possible using the [`getline` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) of `istream`:

```
std::istream is = ...;

const int MAX_BUFFSIZE = 512;
char buffer[MAX_BUFFSIZE];

is.getline(buffer, MAX_BUFFSIZE, '\0');    // Get up to MAX_BUFFSIZE - 1 bytes until the first null character (or end of stream)
```

Note that this removes the delimiter (null character) from the input stream, but does not append it to the buffer (this is the difference between `getline()` and `get()` for this example). However, the null character is automatically appended to the buffer; so, the last byte will contain the null character, but it will be removed from the stream.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the overload:

```
istream& get (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/ will solve your problem; put `'\0'` as `delim`.  There is also a version (shown at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) that will return an `std::string`.